# Which transaction do I have to reattach?

Tags: tangle, address, reattach

I have 5 times reattached the same transaction. All five has status pending. Does it matter which one of them I use for another reattach? Maybe this was the mistake?

Answer (score 3):

If they are all identical transactions, then it doesn't matter which one you reattach. Make sure to wait at LEAST one hour before reattaching.

Comment: Why should I wait until reattach? Isn't the probability of one tx getting confirmed higher if I have multiple of the "same" tx in the tangle? This will result in a lot of invalid tx, but from an egoistic perspective the probability increases?

Comment: @Akkumulator yes that is indeed an egoistic perspective, sinde if you have multiple same tx in the tangle, others who choose to "build on it" will not confirm and have to reattach too.

Comment: Would be good if the fullnodes only accept a certain number of reattaches if the transaction in question is still on a valid part of the tangle.